# How to change CSS of last tab in Bootstrap Tab

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have set the margin-right on my Bootstrap tabs like this:

```
.nav-tabs > li > a {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

However, I want to set the margin-right to zero on the last tab. Ie. If I have three tabs, the first two tabs have a margin-right of 30, and the last tab should have a margin-right of 0.

Any ideas of how to do this? Answers on a postcard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSS [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) pseudoselector to handle this as it will target the last element that matches a given type as expected :

```
.nav-tabs > li:last-of-type > a {
    margin-right: 0;
    /* Define any other styles here */
}
```

You can [see a working example of this here](http://jsbin.com/liqufu/edit?html,css,output) and demonstrated below (using colors to help indicate targeting):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
.nav-tabs > li:last-of-type > a {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
.nav-tabs > li:last-child > a {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML is something like this:

```
<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

You could select the last `li` and give it or its `a` child a margin-right:

```
.nav-tabs > li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}
/*OR*/
.nav-tabs > li:last-of-type > a {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```